# Proxy Authentication Required Error coming while using Google API for translation

Tags: c#, translation, google-api

Am using Google API for translation on passing my request to change the text language its showing the error of "Failed to get the response(407) Proxy Authendication required".

string Text = textBox1.Text;

Text = Translator.Translate(Text, Language.English,    Language.French,Google.API.Translate.TranslateFormat.text);

textBox1.Text = Text;

this is sample code i tried with GoogleTranslationApi.dll please provide me some input to rectify this error.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup you proxy server setting in the app.config.

Here is what I use with ISA proxy server (looks you are also on that).

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy autoDetect="False" usesystemdefault="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: tanq very much i tried with this <system.net> <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"> <proxy/> <bypasslist/> <module/> </defaultProxy> </system.net>its working for me